# Unwanted page refresh after AJAX request that runs SQL

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, ajax, razor

On click of a button, I want to delete something from my database.

The following is my click handler.

```
$('.deleteLesson').click(function () {
    $.get('/Assignment/Modules/DeleteLesson.cshtml?LessonID=' + lessonID,function(data){
    });
});
```

Inside DeleteLesson.cshtml, I have the following

```
var db = Database.Open("database");
db.Query("DELETE FROM Lessons WHERE LessonID=@0", Request.QueryString["LessonID"]);
```

When the `$.get` runs, the SQL is performed on my database, but it forces a refresh on my original page. I can't figure out why. Through troubleshooting I have discovered it is purely the `db.Query` line that causes the refresh, and nothing else.

To be clear: I can comment out the db.Query line and it works exactly as I want it to (except it doesn't delete the item)

Comment: `return false;` after `$.get();` call

Comment: @zerkms No luck, sorry. I assume that must mean it isn't javascript that is forcing me to refresh?

Comment: it is javascript. After the page is loaded - only JS can affect its behaviour

Comment: What does the html look like? What are you clicking?

Comment: @u84six `<div class="deleteLesson">x</div>` I don't think its an issue with the click handler, as it works if the query isn't ran

Comment: Maybe you need to show a bit more of the code behind.

Comment: @u84six Nothing else is really relevant. The AJAX request works, optionally returns data without reloading the page. When the query is included, it refreshes the page.

Comment: Have you tried using a string literal value in place of `Request.QueryString["LessonID"]`?

Comment: inside your `$.get()` please include `console.log(data)` and tell us what you see. Like so: `$.get(url, data, function(data){console.log(data)})`

Comment: @DMason Yeah I tried hard coding values, same result

Comment: @rolodex Nothing is returned, so nothing is put in the console. If I make the file return dummy data, it is logged and then the page reloads

Comment: Show us the HTML structure. Might have something wrong with the structure. This `.deleteLesson` belongs to a form, maybe?

Comment: I think u r using mvc framework. provide Action and controller to $.get. Please tell whick version of mvc are u using

Comment: Check if your javascript is added twice to your page

Comment: Doing database operations in the view is a very bad practice. Don't you have a Controller, a Business o a DataAccess layer?

Comment: @Andy what is `.deleteLesson` ?

Comment: is there any sqldecencies set which is causing data reload ? or anything else that notifies db insert / delete back to page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether to laugh or cry... it turns out my `live.js` was forcing the refreshes as it saw changes and wanted to update the page for me. (As intended, I just never expected it to do it in these circumstances).

Thanks for the help everyone...

Comment: Both laughing and crying in turn sounds appropriate :)

Answer (score 2):

A bit long for a comment - but the fact that it works when not running the query is interesting. What happens if you try the following from the documentation [page](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

1. Request the page and ignore the results - (simplest call):

   ```
   $('.deleteLesson').click(function () {
       $.get('/Assignment/Modules/DeleteLesson.cshtml?LessonID=' + lessonID);
   });
   ```
2. Alert on each of the possible outcomes - see if the handlers invoked make sense or get called at all:

   ```
   var url = '/Assignment/Modules/DeleteLesson.cshtml?LessonID=' + lessonID;
   var jqxhr = $.get(url, function() {
     alert( "success" );
   })
     .done(function() {
       alert( "second success" );
     })
     .fail(function() {
       alert( "error" );
     })
     .always(function() {
       alert( "finished" );
     });
   ```

What about doing this as a post:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/Assignment/Modules/DeleteLesson.cshtml",
data: { LessonID: lessonID }
})
 .done(function() {
    alert( "Record Deleted" );
});
```

Finally, have you tried invoking with `$.ajax` instead of the `$.get` shorthand? This gives you access to additional [options](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$('.deleteLesson').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.get('/Assignment/Modules/DeleteLesson.cshtml?LessonID=' + lessonID,function(data){
     //code here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.deleteLesson').click(function (el, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get('/Assignment/Modules/DeleteLesson.cshtml?LessonID=' + lessonID,function(data){
    });
});
```

also check that lessonID is being passed correctly to the QueryString collection.  The SQL Query may be failing because of this.

Comment: sorry to say we need to preventDefault if its button or hyperlink to stop the default action to be performed.. but that is already a div so it would not make any sense to call **preventDefault()**

Comment: I'm guessing its an anchor, which will preform a synchronous GET by default

Comment: @reach4thelasers see comments by the OP, it is a div.

Answer (score 0):

Create an action in your controller and don't use call to a cshtml page.

```
public class LessonControler{

   [AllowGet]
   public JsonResult DeleteLesson(long LessonID){
      //DoTheDeletion magic here
      return Json(new {Done="OK", Error=""}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }

}
```

And change the javascript to match the new action call

```
$('.deleteLesson').click(function () {
    $.get('/Lesson/DeleteLesson?LessonID=' + lessonID,function(data){
    });
});
```

Or even better transform this to Post [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)